# how to Copy from big table to another table in snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a 7TB+- table in snowflake, I want to pass half of that table to a new table. for example with a country filter. what technique would you recommend? insert into select * from TABLE where COUNTRY = 'A' or use snowpipe to send a parquet format to S3 an then copy into table into snowflake target table

I tried the first option. 5 hours after and the process was on 35%. I read a post where a guy had to scaling the cluster to XL instance. He read another post where snowpipe is the good option. my cluster is only a XS :(

by the way, I have Cluster key and the mission is segment the data by countries by company politics.

The original table is about events from the devices that have the app installed. 30 events per session minute, for example a Uber App or Lyft App

Comment: As a test, can you try cloning the table and then deleting the unwanted rows?

Comment: They have given me several alternatives in communities. materialized view, normal views, insert into select. upload the cluster to xl for a couple of hours

Comment: It all depends on how you plan to use the resulting tables, and how synchronized you'd like them to be. That part is missing from the question.

Comment: sorry.  the original table is about events from the devices that have the app installed. 30 events per session minute, for example a Uber app

Comment: But how do you plan to use the resulting tables? If there will be no updates done to them, and you need to keep them in sync with the master table, then a view will make sense. But depends on the intended use of the results

Comment: yes, I need it to be as up-to-date as the original. MV or only a view? How could you measure the performance of these two options?

Answer (score 1):

An MV will definitely be more performant than a standard view but there is an extra cost associated with that as Snowflake has to keep the MV in sync with the table. Sounds like the table will be rapidly changing so this cost will be continuous.

Another option is to create a stream on the source table and use a task to merge the stream data into the target table. Tasks require a running warehouse but I've found that an XS warehouse is very capable so minimum you're talking 24 credits per day. Tasks also have a minimum 1 minute interval so if you need bleeding edge, that might discount this option

Comment: one of the recommendations in the documentation is
- The view’s base table does not change frequently.
I don't kwon if it apply to me.

Comment: By change I think they are referring to data being inserted/updated as this would mean a constant process running to keep the MV in sync. This would lead to increased cost. A standard view wouldn't incur any extra cost for this. If you explicitly name each column in the SELECT, then new columns wouldn't cause an issue but if you rename a column or use SELECT *, then you would need to update the definitions